# How can I fix this unknown error in this code? (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p Shutdown5=Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds?
If "%INPUT%" == "y" goto yes
If "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no

:yes
echo Shutting down in 5
/t 1
echo Shutting down in 4
/t 1
echo Shutting down in 3
/t 1
echo Shutting down in 2
/t 1
echo Shutting down in 1
/t 1
echo Shutting down.

:no
exit
```

Above is a code that won't work for me. Could anyone point out my mistake, I am 100% unsure...

Comment: If you tell us clearly what does not work we can help you. I guess you did not think of what happens if the user enters something other than `y` or `n`...

Comment: @aschipfl I said go to yes if 'y', go to no if 'n'.

Comment: Yes, but think about where does execution continue if one enters `a`, for instance, so when _both_ conditions are _not_ fulfilled? Ah, and I just recognised that you are querying variable `INPUT` although you are setting variable `Shutdown5`...

Comment: @aschipfl I'll be totally honest here, I am learning. I only am a beginner in this code and I am a bit puzzled. So...if you could help me out in like a beginner language with all due respect, I am not intending to be an offence. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I would look at using the `choice` command as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script can't work because `/t` is not a command. I guess you want to use `TIMEOUT /T 1` which means a timeout for 1 sec. So try this:

```
@echo off
set /p Shutdown5=Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds?
If "%INPUT%" == "y" goto yes
If "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no

:yes
echo Shutting down in 5
timeout /t 1
echo Shutting down in 4
timeout /t 1
echo Shutting down in 3
timeout /t 1
echo Shutting down in 2
timeout /t 1
echo Shutting down in 1
timeout /t 1
echo Shutting down.

:no
exit
```

If you also want to avoid the messages which are echoed by the timeout command, use this instead:

```
timeout /t 1 >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: You missed the obvious. `INPUT` is not defined.

Comment: @DavidPostill how can I fix that?

Comment: @AidenTooMLG `set /p INPUT=Would you like to shutdown your computer in 5 seconds?`